# Databricks AWS memory difference

Tags: amazon-web-services, pytorch, databricks

I'm using Databricks to train/test a model in Pytorch, and I keep hitting memory errors that don't make sense. In the configuration for the Databricks job, I specify the `node_type_id` and `driver_node_type_id` as `g4dn.2xlarge`, which according to [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/g4/) should provide up to 32GB of memory. When I run the job on Databricks, I get an out-of-memory error which says that the GPU only has 14GB of available memory:

`CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 126.00 MiB (GPU 0; 14.76 GiB total capacity; 12.97 GiB already allocated; 99.75 MiB free; 13.20 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation. See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF`

Is there another parameter that I should change in the configuration JSON object to tell Databricks to use the `g4dn.2xlarge` instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Databricks is indeed using the instance type you specified; however, the `g4dn.2xlarge` instance type has 32 GiB of memory, but its GPU only has 16 GiB memory (and some of this is always going to be reserved by the OS, hence your error's 14.76 GiB number).

I recommend finding another instance type that meets the minimum GPU memory requirements for your workload. Because AWS frequently releases new instance types and newer generations I will refrain from recommending a specific instance type, but https://instances.vantage.sh/ is a great way to find instance types with filters that meet your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking at that website now. Do you know how to filter the results based on per-GPU memory? The memory for `g4dn.2xlarge` is listed on the website as 32GB total (under the "Instance Memory" column) but as you just mentioned, the GPU only has 16GB memory.

Comment: Update: there's a hidden column "GPU memory" that includes the per-GPU memory. Thanks!